# Given the SVD of $A$, what's the SVD of $A^*$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

Given the SVD (ie. the $U, \Sigma$, and $V^*$ of $A$), how can we determine the SVD of $A^*$? Do we have to recompute the SVD for $A^*$ or is there a way we can derive $A^*$ from $A$?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $A$, then $A=U\Sigma V^*$ means that $A^* = V\Sigma^*U^*$. $\Sigma$ is real, though, so $\Sigma^*=\Sigma$ (assuming you're using the form of the SVD where $\Sigma$ is square; if not, that's only true for the diagonal part). This means that the SVD of $A^*$ is just $(V,\Sigma,U^*)$.

Comment: Oh got it....so the "new" U = V and the "new" V* = U*?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Great thanks! Does $\Sigma = \Sigma$*?

Comment: Yes. I don't know if you saw my edit, but I added that to my answer.

Comment: @JohnMoeller $\Sigma =\Sigma ^*$ only if $A$ is a square matrix. Otherwise they don't even have the same dimensions, let alone being equal.

Comment: Is $\Sigma$ always real, even when dealing with imaginary numbers?

Comment: @oxuser That's correct. But I'm talking about dimensions. For instance if $A$ is a $3\times 2$ matrix, then $\Sigma$ is $3\times 2$ and $\Sigma ^*$ is $2\times 3$.

Comment: @GitGud: There's a form of the SVD that I usually use that makes $\Sigma$ square and one of $U$ or $V$ have the same dimensions as $A$ (so in your example, $U$ would be $3\times 2$ but $\Sigma$ and $V$ would be $2\times 2$), but you're right to point it out, since there's some ambiguity there.

Comment: @oxuser : yes, $\Sigma$ is always real. $\Sigma$ contains the singular values of $A$ and zeros. The singular values are also square roots of the eigenvalues of either $A^*A$ or $AA^*$. Those two matrices have the property that they're _positive semidefinite_, which means (among other things) that their eigenvalues are real and nonnegative. So the singular values must be real too, and so must be $\Sigma$.

Comment: edited to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

If $A=U\Sigma V^*$, then $A^*=V\Sigma ^* U^*=V\Sigma ^T U^*$.

We still need to guarantee that this a SVD decomposition for $A^*$. Obviously $V$ and $U^*$ are unitary matrices. Now for $\Sigma ^T$, does $A^*$ have the same singular values as $A$? Yes, because $AA^*$ and $A^*A$ have the same non-negative eigenvalues.

Comment: You have a typo in your $A^*=V\Sigma^*U^*$.

Comment: Great thanks! Does $\Sigma = \Sigma$*?  I know it's true with the real Transpose, but not sure if the conjugate is any different.

Comment: @$\mathbb{R} ^n$ Thanks. Nice nickname, by the way.

Comment: @oxuser No! $\Sigma \neq \Sigma ^*$ in general. They're only equal when $A$ is a square matrix. If $A$ isn't a square matrix, they don't even have the same dimensions. That's why the the observation about non-negative eigenvalues is useful. The multiplicty of the eigenvalue $0$ (in case it is an eigenvalue of one of the matrices $AA^*$ and $A^*A$) is what what will make things work.

Comment: Wait, doesn't the diagonal not change when you take the transpose of it?

Comment: @oxuser No, the main diagonal will remain the same, even if $\Sigma $ isn't a square matrix.

Comment: Oh got it, so basically all of the values in the diagonal will be the same (since it's a diagonal matrix). It's just that the dimensions would change. Correct?

Comment: @oxuser That's correct. I gotta go to bed now. See you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Git Gud!

Comment: @oxuser No problem.